# Why can I cast implicitly an integer to a char in C

Tags: c, casting, integer, char

I was wondering, why is casting implicitly from an integer to a char possible in C ?

If for example :

```
int i = 2789;

printf("%c\n",i);
```

would give me a char back, because it would have truncated the bits starting from the most significant ones.
But usually you can't really cast implicitly if it means you'll lose in precision so why can I do it here ?

Comment: If you had warnings on i would guess it would warn you

Comment: `printf` promotes to integer anyway (so there's no cast) and the compiler cannot check type against a specifier in a format string. From the compiler's perspective, since there's no mismatch here since (in other words) it doesn't see the parameter `i` as having to be a `char`.

Comment: @mbratch: Many modern compilers (including GCC) have special handling for `printf`-like functions, and will indeed check the format string and find the `%c`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no implicit cast going on here.

`printf` is a *variadic* function, which means that any arguments of type `char` are converted up to `int` before the function is called.  Your argument is already of type `int`, so no conversion occurs.

Comment: Technically speaking, the arguments are not converted to `int`s, but to the CPUs word size. On x86-64, for example, they are promoted to 64 bits, even though `int`s are 32 bits long.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Arguments to variadic functions undergo the default argument promotions, which include integer promotion.  Integer promotion states that anything less than an `int` is converted to an `int` (or `unsigned int`, as appropriate).  There's no notion of "CPU word size" in the C standard.

Comment: Ah, true enough. I guess, in fact, both things are going on in this case: `int` promotion for variadic functions, and word-size promotion for integer argument passing in general. The latter being defined by the platform-specific ABI rather than the C standard, of course.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Perhaps.  But if there's word-size promotion at the ABI level, that's "invisible" from within the confines of C, though.

Comment: Invisible for programs that are written in strict and correct C, at least. I guess it is true that `int` promotion being at work here, however, means that the program in the question is correct and well-defined from the viewpoint of strict C, though, as opposed to my initial assumption.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Yes indeed, in strict C ;)  In terms of type-conversion and stuff, the behaviour of the OP's code is well-defined.  I'm not sure what happens if you ask `printf` to interpret a value like `2789` via `%c`, though...

Comment: Yes. My point was that, even in the absence of C defining `int` promotion for arguments to variadic functions (which I overlooked), the code would still have worked properly almost to the point of being "well-defined" on the vast majority of normally used ABIs.

Answer (score 0):

All integral arguments passed to a function are generally promoted to the CPU's word size, so regardless if you pass a `char`, `short`, `int` or `long`, the physical layout of the stack and/or registers upon entry to `printf` is the same anyway.

Therefore, there's no "cast" going on, merely normal argument passing.

That's not to say that the code is correct, however. Argument passing and type promotion is defined in the ABI, not by C, so it may not work on all platforms. (Though it will work on the vast majority.)

Comment: True enough. (As long as you make that "any type bigger than the word size", at least.)

Comment: See my comment below my answer.  Also, type promotion **is** specified by the C standard.  The ABI just defines how that's physically implemented.